# In swift 5, left side of my collectionView is stuck when I scroll further right

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a collection view on the main viewController, and as for the layout, I am using `collectionViewFlowLayout()`. Whenever I start up the app in landscape mode, it seems like the left part of the screen is stuck just like how you can see in the image. It works perfectly fine with other iPhone devices prior to X series. I think there must be a constraint issue that I am not familiar with.

Image stuck on left side:
[image: Image stuck on left side]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've setup the constraints with Safe Area

[image]

instead of Superview

[image]

Changing it to superview should fix the problem